# Locals filtering by name

Tags: r

In Python, I can do something like this:

```
ss1 = '1'
ss2 = '2'
ss3 = '3'
print('\n'.join([v for k, v in locals().items() if k.startswith('ss')]))
```

Thus, getting all the local variables which start with the string 'ss' and printing them to the console.

Is there any way to do this in R? I've looked for ways to get a variable's name, which yields something like `deparse(substitute(?))` but I'm unclear on the syntax there. Nor do I see a way to access a `locals()`-like function.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at `ls()`.

In your case probably something like:

```
cat(grep("^ss", ls(), value = TRUE), sep = "\n")
```